# MYSQL pivoting rows and limiting by rows of a specific column

Tags: mysql

Not entirely sure how to word the question so I gave it my best show and am hoping that the explanation will help get the point across.  Any questions, please ask.

I have the following setup for my database:

```
create table spooner_pec
(
  id int,
  year varchar(20),
  policy_number int,
  primary_name varchar(200),
  experience_rate decimal(10,2),
  mco_name varchar(200)
);
```

with these values being inserted:

```
insert into spooner_pec values
(1,'2009',183586,'ZBIN LANDSCAPING INC', 1.22, 'GENEX CARE FOR OHIO'),
(1,'2011',183586,'ZBIN LANDSCAPING INC', 0.93, 'COMPMANAGEMENT HEALTH SYSTEMS, INC.'),
(1,'2012',183586,'ZBIN LANDSCAPING INC', 0.92, 'HEALTH MANAGEMENT SOLUTIONS, INC.'),
(1,'2013',183586,'ZBIN LANDSCAPING INC', 0.50, 'CAREWORKS'),
(1,'2014',183586,'ZBIN LANDSCAPING INC', 0.47, 'UNIVERSITY HOSPITALS COMPCARE'),
(1,'2010',183586,'ZBIN LANDSCAPING INC', 1.27, 'SHEAKLEY UNICOMP')
```

The query that I have working so far is this:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(case when year = ',
      year,
      ' then experience_rate end) AS `',
      year, '-Pen`'
    ) ORDER BY year
  ) INTO @sql
FROM
  spooner_pec;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT policy_number, primary_name, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM spooner_pec 
                   GROUP BY policy_number');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

So I have one row for each company and then a year-pen column for each year.  What I need to do now is only get the rows where the penalty of the latest year is greater than 1, for example.  So if the last year entered for all the data was 2014, I need where 2014-Pen, in this case, is > 1.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c2b88/9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do another query to get the last year, and merge that into the SQL.

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(case when year = ',
      year,
      ' then experience_rate end) AS `',
      year, '-Pen`'
    ) ORDER BY year
  ) INTO @sql
FROM
  spooner_pec;
SELECT MAX(year) INTO @lastYear FROM spooner_pec;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT policy_number, primary_name, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM spooner_pec 
                   GROUP BY policy_number
                   HAVING `', @lastYear, '-Pen` > 1');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```